# Can you please help me with my Eclipse build error

Tags: eclipse

I have made a basic Android App for my studies in Eclipse 2020-12 (lines up with the study module).

Now I want to run my app in the emulator to test it, but when I click on Run (the green little arrow), I get the error below. How do I fix it?

I followed these steps to install and setup my Eclipse:

https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-setup-android-for-eclipse-ide

I have the following installed:

JRE 1.8.0,
jdk-7u80-windows-x64,
eclipse2020-12-inst-jre-win64,
Java 8,
Android SDK

Keep in mind, I am new to all of this so you will have to give me Android for Dummies step by step instructions, lol.

[image]

Edit:

- Extra Info

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long now, Android Studio is the only supported option.

Comment: Thanks Greg, the problem I have is studies I am doing wants a relative layout, so the constraint one is giving me a lot of errors in Android Studio.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run your code? Which one is on the Java Build Path to build against? Is the BASE64Encoder class present in it?

Comment: @nitind see the screenshots I have added. I hope that answers your questions.